# Method not present class linking issue: when calling methods from classes with same name and project path in two linked java projects

Tags: java, buildpath

I have simulated two systems as two java project in eclipse and thus both projects have files with the same name and project path.

When `project1.Class1` refers to `project2.Class2`, `Class2` must refer to its dependent files say `classes3` from `Project2`.

Instead, it uses `Project1` file `classes3` at runtime due to the same name and project path.

I have already added `project1` in `project2` through Build Path Configurations of `project2`.

How to resolve this runtime linking issue in java?

Comment: Possibly an issue of circular dependency. Is Project 2 dependent on Project 1 as well?

Comment: no project2 has no dependency on project1. Project1 & 2 is the simulation of two similar systems and the calling passes from project1 to project2.

Comment: Can you first explain why the two projects contain classes with the same name, and whether the classes are actually the same, or if they perform different functions?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to create a custom class loader at start up which will take the responsibility of finding all the classes the program references, and keeping the two conflicting classes separated.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html